# Command-line CPU frequency scaling?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, electrical-power

How to configure Ubuntu 12.04 Server to dynamically adjust CPU frequency during quiet times?

I've found a set of instructions at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=944190, suggesting to add acpi-cpufreq to /etc/modules, modprobe it, and then put one of (powersave, performance, ondemand, conservative) into the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` files.

But on my system, those files don't exist:

```
user@pc:~$ ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/
cache        microcode  subsystem         topology
crash_notes  power      thermal_throttle  uevent
```

There's an empty directory at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq`, but

```
user@pc:~$ sudo echo conservative > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

gives error:

```
-bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
```

Intel Atom CPU, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What kind of Intel Atom do you have ? As far as I remember most of the Atoms don't support SpeedStep.

Comment: Atom D2550 apparently, part of a Jetway JNC9KDL-2550 motherboard.  It's potentially a fanless passively-cooled computer, if we can convince the CPU to quieten-down while not in use.

Comment: According to [intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/65470) it does not support SpeedStep. It's maximal TDP is 10W so most probably Intel decided to remove this feature.